# How do you inject dependencies to tree objects with backward references?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, compositionroot

How do I generate a composition root which creates a tree of object with backward (parent-references).

Imagine the following simple node object of which I'd like to construct a binary tree:

```
class Node
{
   public Node Parent{get;}

   public Node Child1{get;}
   public Node Child2{get;}

   public Node(Node parent, Node child1, Node child2)
   { 
      Parent = parent;
      Child1 = child1;
      Child2 = child2;
   }
}
```

Here is where I am stuck:

```
public void CompositionRoot()
{
   //example of a parent node with 
   Node Parent = new Node
                     (  
                         null, //the parent has no parent node 
                         new Node
                             ( /* ??? here should come the reference to the parent node, 
                                  but since it's inside its own constructor I have 
                                  no reference yet */                 
                                 , null //the child node contains no further child
                                 , null 
                             )
                      )
}
```

Am I on the wrong path to try to combine the principle of dependency injection with this sort of object graph because it contains circular dependencies? What would be the solution?

Comment: You can't create the parent node without first creating both child nodes. You can't create either child node without first creating the parent node. Even without DI, you can't create this object graph beyond the simple case of a single node with no parent and no children.

Comment: Your object graphs are cyclic and this is only possible when yuo revert to using property injection. Whether or not this is the best solution for your problem, or a change of design depends on the actual details. Your example, however, is abstract, making it hard to give any useful feedback on your design.

Comment: @Steven I tried to reduced the example to a minimal comprehensible one. Concretely we are talking about a GUI hierarchy with subwindows\tabs\dialogs where the subdialogs know their parents. Today the subwindows are created by their parents when the dialog is constructed and they (the parents) inject themselves in the subwindows in their constructor.